# Lotus Script: Passing a string variable to Evaluate statement

Tags: lotusscript, lotus, evaluate

I can't get simple DbLookup formula working with a variable. I have a view with employees and their managers, i get unique managers' records with DbColumn and then i need a list of people managed by this person

```
pms=Evaluate({@Unique(@Dbcolumn("":"";"":"";"admin";3))})

ForAll pm In pms
   result = Evaluate({@DBlookup("":"";"":"";"admin";} & pm & {;1)})
```

this doesn't work, i have also tried using vertical bars and additional quotation marks around pm but i keep getting either type mismatch or execution failed errors

```
result = Evaluate({@DBlookup("":"";"":"";"admin";} & "keyword" & {;1)})
```

this works fine

Comment: Do you have in your test data elements in pms which contain an quotation mark?

Comment: No. I do have slashes though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclose the value of pm in quotation marks too:

```
result = Evaluate({@DBlookup("":"";"":"";"admin";"} & pm & {";1)})
```

This way it is recognized as a string.

Example:

If pm has a string value "Domino" then Evaluate string has to look like this:

```
@DBlookup("":"";"":"";"admin";"Domino";1)
```

but in your original formula version it would be

```
@DBlookup("":"";"":"";"admin";Domino;1)
```

BTW, the code would break if pm would contain a quotation mark. If you are sure that can't happen then the code is fine.

Comment: i have tried it before and tried it now again - type mismatch, CStr(pm) doesn't help either. there's no way for pm to contain a quotation mark

Comment: You get a type mismatch if you handle `result` like a string but it is an array. Use `result(0)` instead e.g. `print(result(0))`.

Comment: i don't. the result array is empty every time i get an error ( isEmpty(result) returns True) and the only way i use it is in another ForAll loop to pick single records and create a separate list so the issue is still within Evaluate :)

Comment: You look in first column for value of pm and return first column - does that make sense? @DbLookup always looks for key in first sorted column (probably not the third column with managers)

Comment: and that's a score! i'm almost sure i took it under consideration before but it seems that i forgot : ) thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you need a resorted view: first sorted column with managers and second column with managed people.